# How to make objects suddenly stop

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am pretty new to Blender so please bare with me, as I'm sure this question has a very simple answer.

I'm making a scene where my character falls and hits the ground. By default, Blender smooths movements like this, but obviously things don't slow down before they hit the ground, they just come to an abrupt stop. I just want to know how to stop my character from decelerating (and accelerating) so that I can make this fall seem real. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The default interpolation mode is smooth, in the graph editor select the keyframes on the graph you want to stop suddenly. Then go to the menu:

Key>Interpolation mode>Linear

This will make acceleration and stopping at the same speed from start to finish. This should help you accomplish your goal.